# Function composition errors

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and I came across a situation in which I'm not entirely sure what is going on.

I'm working on a bigger project, and have been trying to 'simplify' my code. I'd learnt about function composition and I think I mostly understand it. However, whilst pushing the limits of this, I encountered a situation I'm not sure how to explain.

After a few hours of fiddling about with it, I boiled it down to this:

```
foo1 x y z = x == (y && z)
foo2 x y z = (x ==) . (&&) y z     -- Error
foo3 x y   = (x ==) . (&&) y
foo4 x     = (x ==) . (&&)         -- Error
```

Why do `foo1` and `foo3` work, whilst `foo2` and `foo4` give errors when I try to define them? As far as I know, there's no reason adding or removing equivalent arguments to both the input and output should change the function.

**Edit: Include errors**

`foo2` yields the error:

```
<interactive>:1:23: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> a1’ with actual type ‘Bool’
    • Possible cause: ‘(&&)’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(&&) y z’
      In the expression: (x ==) . (&&) y z
      In an equation for ‘foo2’: foo2 x y z = (x ==) . (&&) y z
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: a1 (bound at <interactive>:1:6)
        foo2 :: a1 -> Bool -> Bool -> a -> Bool
          (bound at <interactive>:1:1)
```

Whilst `foo4` gives the error:

```
<interactive>:2:15: error:
    • No instance for (Eq (Bool -> Bool))
        arising from an operator section
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(x ==)’
      In the expression: (x ==) . (&&)
      In an equation for ‘foo4’: foo4 x = (x ==) . (&&)
```

Comment: Specifically, what errors?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have updated the question with the error messages.

Comment: I posted an answer, but I'm not proficient enough in Haskell to figure out the second error on my current mental state. With `foo2`, you're fully applying `&&`, so you should be using application (`$`), not composition (`.`).

Comment: Okay, that's helpful. So `(.)` needs exactly 1 argument unapplied, whereas `($)` needs exactly 0. Is it even possible to leave 2 arguments unapplied, as I tried to do in `foo4`?

Comment: `$` is just function application, as it's name suggests. `.` expects a function. If you fully apply `&&`, you're not giving `.` a fucntion.

Comment: Why don't you post an example of one of your calls, that is a function applied to some input parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### function application

Let's start with function application.

`a b` is an application of a function a to one arguments b.

`a b c` is an application of a function a to two arguments b and c.

`a b c d` is an application of a function a to three arguments b, c, and d.

### (&&) and (.)'s type signature

Then look at these two functions' type signature.

```
(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
```

takes two arguments

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

takes three arguments, two of them functions

Then we look into these four cases.

### foo1

```
foo1 x y z = x == (y && z)
```

(y && z) is (&&) y z, fully applied. So the result is a Bool type.

x == Bool is (==) x Bool. So x is a Bool type.

It works.

### foo2

```
foo2 x y z = (x ==) . (&&) y z
```

(x ==) is a function that expects one argument.

so `(x ==) . :: (a -> b) -> a -> c`

However, as @Carcigenicate says, your (&&) is fully applied.

Hence, compiler say, "Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> a1’ with actual type ‘Bool’"

### foo3

```
foo3 x y   = (x ==) . (&&) y

(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

(.) function composition takes function ( x==) and (&&) y

and all it need now is another a to produce c.

so foo3 is just foo1's point-free style.

It works, too.

### foo4

```
foo4 x     = (x ==) . (&&)
```

So we already meet (x ==) .

its type signature is (a -> b) -> a -> c

However, (&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool

Although it can be seen as Bool -> (Bool -> Bool), a function that takes one argument and produce a Bool -> Bool function.

(Bool->Bool) is not an instance for Eq. It doesn't have (==).

Thus the compiler says "No instance for (Eq (Bool -> Bool))"

### Point-free style

> As far as I know, there's no reason adding or removing equivalent
>   arguments to both the input and output should change the function.

It holds true when they are on the same level.

name b c d = function b c d --fully applied

name b c = function b c --wait one argument

name b = function b --wait two arguments

name = function --wait three/all arguments

but function composition needs to compose two one-argument functions into one-argument function(and the right one's output type need to match the left one's input type.)

So the order is function application first, then (.) / function composition second. And you need to feed (b->c) and (a->b) to (.) to get a new (a->c) function.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now. It never occurred to me that `(&&) x y` would bind first, because it doesn't have brackets round it. Thank you.